# Result is not expected when use may_alias to struct

Tags: c++11, gcc, struct

When I use -O2 to compile this code, the result is not what I expected. I expected it works and return 0. However it doesn't change the f1. I wonder if I can use may_alias to struct like this:

```
struct my_struct1
{

    int i[2];
    char a;
};


typedef struct my_struct1 __attribute__((__may_alias__))  t_my_struct1;

int main (void)
{

    float f1=4.0e+4;
    t_my_struct1 *sptr2 = (t_my_struct1 *)&f1;
    sptr2->i[0] = 0;
    sptr2->i[1] = 0;
    if(f1 != 0.0f)
        return 1;// may_alias doesn't work

    return 0;// may_alias works

}
```

Comment: What's the result for -O0 and -O3?

Comment: The compiler says `warning: ignoring attributes applied to 'struct my_struct1' after definition [-Wattributes]`, which I guess is a hint as to why the may_alias attribute doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Even if you could fix the aliasing, there is another problem. On my platform at least, a `float` takes up only 4 bytes, the same as one `int`. Therefore, `sptr2->i[1]` will be out of bounds. Perhaps you mean to use a `double` instead? And, then, include a static assertion that `sizeof(double) <= sizeof(int [2])`.